# Create a bash script inside a bash script that uses special variables $1, $#

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a script that creates an other script that uses $1 and $#, the problem is that those variables are being interpreted by the first script, so they are empty. Here's my problem, the first script creates the script `/tmp/test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

cat << EOF > /tmp/test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $#
EOF
```

The result in `/tmp/test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 
echo 0
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this and get in `/tmp/test.sh` `$1` and `$#`?

I would like to have in `/tmp/test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $#
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the here-document delimiter so that the contents of the here document are treated as literal text (i.e., as if occurring in a single-quoted string).

```
cat << 'EOF' > /tmp/test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $#
EOF
```

*Any* quoting will work, not just single quotes. The only important thing is that at least one character be escaped.

- `cat << \EOF`
- `cat << "EOF"`
- `cat << E"O"F`
- etc